# Format the x-axis ticks

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've got the following code that generates a surface density plot. 
x and y are position co=ordinates and z axis represents the density. All the values are pre calculated and is stored in a numpy array.

```
    #set up the grid
xi, yi = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), 200), np.linspace(y.min(), y.max(), 200)
xi, yi = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)
#interpolate
rbf = scipy.interpolate.Rbf(x, y, z, function='linear')
zi = rbf(xi, yi)

plt.imshow(zi, vmin=z.min(), vmax=z.max(), origin='lower', extent=[x.min(), x.max(), y.min(), y.max()])
plt.scatter(x, y, c=z,marker='o')
plt.colorbar()
plt.scatter(xo,yo, c='b', marker='*')

plt.xlabel("RA(degrees)")
plt.ylabel("DEC(degrees)")
plt.title('Surface Density Plot 2.0 < z < 2.2')
plt.savefig('2.0-2.2.png', dpi= 300 )

plt.show()
```

The problem I have is the xaxis ticks are not in user friendly terms, they are values between 150-152 but I can't seem to change the ticks positions using the xticks() function. 
Would anyone have a suggestion how I can go about to formatting the x axis?

edit-
These are the values for xyz used for the plot. x,y,z are three numpy arrays- https://www.dropbox.com/s/l03pkzplqmfm1su/xyz.csv
the first row is x values, second the y and third the z.

Comment: Using xticks is the correct method to manually set the x axis ticks. Usually something of the form `plt.xticks(plt.arange(150,152,0.5))` would be appropriate. The argument of `xticks` is the key here, can you give the code you have tried to use?

Comment: @user2145647 thanks, but the issue I have is even the ticks change with the plt.xticks(xticks) function with xticks=[150.05,150.10,150.15,150.20,150.25]  , the x  axis still ends up having wierd units of 1.5e2 multiples

Comment: @user2145647 this link has the output image
 dropbox.com/s/bxji5sa84i1bsyz/2.0-2.2.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the pyplot interface, you can set the xticks via (provided you imported matplotlib.pyplot as plt)

```
plt.xticks(*args, **kwargs)
```

You can give the ticks-locations eg. as a list or a numpy array and the tick-labels as a touple (or list, ...).

However, please include a minimal example of code that we can run, so we can test if it's working and see why not, if that's the case. Also, you seem to have imported matplotlib as plt, but some of your commands (like `xlabel`) lack the `plt.` part. Is this just a typo or copy/paste error?

If you want more fine-tuning for your ticks and the tick-format, you should consider using the OO interface of matplotlib. Yes, it's more verbose and you have to type some more letters, but in my opinion the code gets much clearer and you have more possibilities to adapt the graph to your expectations.

**Edit:** As I understand from your comments, you are not satisfied with the format of the xtick labels. So instead of "0.0" "+1.5e2" you probably want to have "150.0" or so. The function to look into (using the pyplot interface) is:

```
plt.ticklabel_format(**kwargs)
```

The kwargs are shown here [here](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html). You should try, if `style='plain'` fits your demands.

Again I want to stress, that the OO interface grants you far more versatility to change the format of the tick labels. The respective functions would be:

```
matplotlib.axes.yaxis.set_major_formatter()
matplotlib.axes.xaxis.set_major_formatter()
```

You can choose between several formatters or even write your own formating function. If you want to do that, I can give you further advice.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I did that and as I was mentioning to user2145647 the number of ticks and their positions change accordingly but they are still in the same units of 1.5e2 and not 150.1 etc.

Comment: This link has the output image I get
https://www.dropbox.com/s/bxji5sa84i1bsyz/2.0-2.2.png

Comment: @firefly: I have edited my answer above, I hope I now understood what you meant.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I would prefer to use my own formatting function, which will surely be more useful in the long run. I tried to search through Matplotlib to how to do that but haven't been able to locate a good help file. Would you have any suggestions?

Comment: @firefly: You can have a look at the [official documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html). However, it's not very comprehensive when it comes to examples or so. Basically you do something like `ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter( FuncFormatter(your_formatter) )`, where `your_formatter` is a function that takes the arguments `x` and `pos`, where `x` is the "tick value" (eg. 150) and `pos` the position, and returns a string which is printed at the tick marks. A small example (although pylab) is given [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/custom_ticker1.html).

Answer (score 0):

Firefly, based on the [dropbox image](http://dropbox.com/s/bxji5sa84i1bsyz/2.0-2.2.png) you have given in the comments I believe the following describes your problem. The magnitude of the x data is much larger than the variations, so python has a list of values like

```
[150.05,150.10,150.15,150.20,150.25]
```

which is too large for the xaxis in this figure so python does some clever business which you do not like (and I agree).

One fix could be to simply set the xticks vertical e.g

```
py.xticks(rotation='vertical')
```

Failing that you could manually do what python has attempted, subtract 150 degrees from the x axis and change your xlabel such that you have

```
plt.xlabel("RA+150(degrees)")
```

If your data was not degrees I would instead suggest rescaling instead (e.g divide by 1e2) but with degrees this looks very strange.

Comment: the vertical function isn't what I'm looking for, it does give more space out for clarity but I would rather have less ticks with a linear scale in it.